I want to display the "No Images" products at the end of a category listings. How can we achieve this sorting with best magento 2 practices?
In magento 2.4.x Category listing page. I want to move all the products which have NO IMAGES at the end OR you can say at the last page. What is the best practice of magento 2 to achieve this customization? Do we have to create a plugin for that? OR can we do it within the list.phtml which loads $block->getLoadedProductCollection?
Can any ever create a sortings like this then please let me know.

To display products without images at the end of a category listing in Magento 2, you'll need to implement custom sorting logic that considers whether a product has an image or not. Magento 2 provides sorting via the collection of products, so the goal is to modify the product collection to add a custom condition for sorting.

the best way is to create a custom module to override the behavior of the product collection.
Use an observer or a plugin to modify the product collection before it is displayed.
In the observer/plugin, you can filter or order the products by checking whether they have images.
